# How can I prevent this repetition of results when merge sorting an array of strings?

Tags: java

I have written a merge sort algorithm which sorts an array containing ID's which I want to sort the array by, then there is a 1d string array containing the full information about each record in the same order as the array of IDs

ID array: `[0,10,1,1,12,16,26,18,24,53,53,53,100]`

String array: `["1,0,Test Name,1,First", "2,10,Another Name,2,First"... etc]`

The merge sorting algorithm then runs and sorts the array of IDs, performing the exact same actions on the string array, as a way of sorting strings using a merge sort.

However, while the array of IDs is sorted properly, with the output being `[0, 1, 1, 10, 12, 16, 18, 24, 26, 53, 53, 53, 100]`, when the string array is sorted the output becomes repeated and incorrect.

```
 Actual Array: 
 
  [ 
Booking Number: 1 
Flight Number: 0 
Passenger Name: Test Name 
Seat Number: 1 
Seat Class: First
,  
Booking Number: 2 
Flight Number: 10 
Passenger Name: Another Name 
Seat Number: 2 
Seat Class: First
,  
Booking Number: 1 
Flight Number: 0 
Passenger Name: Test Name 
Seat Number: 1 
Seat Class: First
,  
Booking Number: 1 
Flight Number: 0 
Passenger Name: Test Name 
Seat Number: 1 
Seat Class: First
,  
Booking Number: 1 
Flight Number: 0 
Passenger Name: Test Name 
Seat Number: 1 
Seat Class: First
,  
Booking Number: 2 
Flight Number: 10 
Passenger Name: Another Name 
Seat Number: 2 
Seat Class: First
,  
Booking Number: 1 
Flight Number: 0 
Passenger Name: Test Name 
Seat Number: 1 
Seat Class: First
,  
Booking Number: 2 
Flight Number: 10 
Passenger Name: Another Name 
Seat Number: 2 
Seat Class: First
,  
Booking Number: 1 
Flight Number: 0 
Passenger Name: Test Name 
Seat Number: 1 
Seat Class: First
,  
Booking Number: 1 
Flight Number: 0 
Passenger Name: Test Name 
Seat Number: 1 
Seat Class: First
,  
Booking Number: 2 
Flight Number: 10 
Passenger Name: Another Name 
Seat Number: 2 
Seat Class: First
,  
Booking Number: 1 
Flight Number: 0 
Passenger Name: Test Name 
Seat Number: 1 
Seat Class: First
,  
Booking Number: 2 
Flight Number: 10 
Passenger Name: Another Name 
Seat Number: 2 
Seat Class: First
]
```

Whereas it should be sorted by the flight ID column. Running it through in the debugger it is hard to see anything but I initially though it could be because I was calling the method to flatten the array repeatedly when the mergeSort algorithm is recursively called, but I moved that variable declaration out of the method and into the class constructor and the same problem still persists, so I'm at a loss as for what to try now.

Code:

```
   public void mergeSort(int[] flightIDArr, int arrLength, String[] actualArr) {

//        Flattened array of bookings to 1d array
            String[] flatArray = flattenArray(readBookings());
            

//         If array does not need to be split as length is already 1
        if (arrLength < 2) {
            return;
        }

        // Middle of the array
        int mid = arrLength / 2;
        //Left array of length of half of the array
        int[] left = new int[mid];
        // Other half of split array, with arrLength-mid size to ensure that it works even if the array is an odd length
        int[] right = new int[arrLength - mid];

        //Mirrored version of previous lines but for string array of what we actually want to sort (booking info)
        String[] actualLeft = new String[mid];
        // Same as above but right side
        String[] actualRight = new String[arrLength - mid];

        // for the elements in left array
        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
            // filling the left arrays with the info from the full array
            left[i] = flightIDArr[i];
            actualLeft[i] = flatArray[i];

        }
        // for elements in right array
        for (int i = mid; i < arrLength; i++) {
            // filling the right arrays with the info from the full array
            right[i - mid] = flightIDArr[i];
            actualRight[i - mid] = flatArray[i];
        }

        //recursively calls the mergesort algorithm to split the arrays as small as possible
        mergeSort(left, mid, actualLeft);
        mergeSort(right, arrLength - mid, actualRight);

        //re merges the split arrays
        merge(flightIDArr,actualArr, left, right, mid, arrLength - mid, actualLeft,actualRight);
    }

    //Method to merge all the split arrays
    public void merge(
            int[] flightIDArr, String[] actualArr, int[] leftArr, int[] rightArr, int left, int right, String[] actualLeft, String[] actualRight) {

        //setting up variables for looping
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        //
        while (i < left && j < right) {
            if (leftArr[i] <= rightArr[j]) {
                flightIDArr[k] = leftArr[i];
                actualArr[k++] = actualLeft[i++];
            }
            else {
                flightIDArr[k] = rightArr[j];
                actualArr[k++] = actualRight[j++];
            }
        }
        while (i < left) {
            flightIDArr[k] = leftArr[i];
            actualArr[k++] = actualLeft[i++];

        }
        while (j < right) {
            flightIDArr[k] = rightArr[j];
            actualArr[k++] = actualRight[j++];

        }
//        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ActualArr));
//        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(flightIDArr));
        System.out.println(" Actual Array: \n \n  " +(Arrays.toString (actualArr)));
    }
```

Edit for output of string array:

Despite performing the exact same actions on each array in the algorithm, the string array somehow ends up being filled with just the first 2 values of the array. To make the info easier to digest when debugging, I modified the 2 arrays to be the same, only containing numbers but with one of them still being a string version like so:

Int array: `[33,10,1,1,12,16,26,18,24,53,53,53,100]`
String array: `["33","10","1","1","12","16","26","18","24","53","53","53","100"]`

Results:
Int array: `[1, 1, 10, 12, 16, 18, 24, 26, 33, 53, 53, 53, 100]`
String array:`[10, 33, 33, 33, 10, 33, 10, 33, 33, 33, 10, 33, 10]`

Stepping through with breakpoints results in nothing useful, just showing numbers somehow desynchronised despite the actions being performed in the same loops of the merge method, but with the string array values getting stuck as either 33 or 10, the first 2 values in the array.

Edit 2:

Flat array contents from debugger currently: `["33", "10", "1", "1", "12", +8 more]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is in the `flattenArray` method that you haven't shown. I couldn't see any obvious problems in your code so I ran it but replaced the references to `flatArray` to `actualArray` and it worked exactly as you'd expect. Try breaking with your debugger after the array is flattened and check the contents of `flatArray`.

Comment: I have tested the flat array individually, and it's contents are as expected, also currently working without even using the flat array method, just using a predefined array of strings. edited the question with the contents for you to see anyway.

Comment: When I run your code without the flat array method I get both arrays sorted correctly. So unfortunately it's a bit hard to offer any other help.

Comment: You were right actually I've been looking at this all day and completely missed it, but so glad to finally have that done.